# Конвейерная обработка HTTP . Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, asyncio, взлом

Интересует вопрос про конвейерную обработку `HTTP (HTTP-pipelining)`

HTTP pipelining (переводится как Конвейерная обработка HTTP) — технология, которая позволяет передавать на сервер сразу несколько запросов в одном соединении, не ожидая соответствующих ответов.

Как я знаю самая популярная **http** библиотека `requests` не поддерживает данную функцию, а вот `aiohttp` и `grequests` вроде бы да.

Самая функциональная по моему мнению `http-библиотека` будет `japronto`. Но я с ней не разу не сталкивался, только прочитал что она умеет и как она действует. Статей про неё нету, не на англ, не на русском.

Мне надо создать огромную нагрузку на сервер. Говорится что `japronto` умеет посылать более **1м** запросов в секунду, обходя `NodeJS` и `golang`. Если кто-то работал с `japronto` киньте примера кода, или статей про неё. `aiohttp` меня не сильно впечатлила.

Japronto как я понял, идет только на `linux`, `macos`, на `windows 10` не пойдет. Тогда, есть ли достойная альтернатива `Japronto`?

Comment: Если ваша цель — тупо создать нагрузку и не получать ответ, можно просто открыть обычный сокет (обернув его в tls, если https) и зафлудить через него запросами)

Comment: @andreymal неа, уже распробовал все варианты, от тупа зафлудить пользы не будет, флуд через сокеты не корыстны.. Все ровно не когда в жизни не создадите такую нагрузку даже с multithreading чтоб пиковая нагрузка на сервер превышало бы хотя бы 1 гиг, с учетом того что это все фильтруется.

Comment: Что такое «нагрузка на сервер 1 гиг»? Любая библиотека будет использовать сырые сокеты внутри себя, если для вас не подходят сырые сокеты по причине производительности — значит задачу решить невозможно даже теоретически

Comment: @andreymal ну как я вас понял, самым производительным будет tcp-сокеты. А если сделать что-то типа ddos атаки правда python плох в производительности, и реализовать будет трудно. Но можно сделать что-то по типу валидации, отправка get запроса на адреса заканчивающиеся на check?uri=  . Или я что-то не понимаю в распределенной атаки ?